# Showing well–definedness after showing multiplicativity

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show for an abelan group $A$ that $A/A^p\cong A_p$ where $A_p= \{ x:x^p=1 \}$ and $A^p= \{x^p:x\in A \}$. For the map I defined $\psi(xA^p)=x$, it is hard to show well–definedness without showing multiplicative property. Is it okay to do that?

Comment: What is “the multiplicative property”?

Comment: $\psi(xyA^p)=xy=\psi(xA^p)\psi(yA^p)$

Comment: You need to show that $xA^p=yA^p$ implies that $x=y$.  Is that really true?

Comment: I still think you have your super/subscripts misplaced.  The standard argument maps $A$ to $A^p$ by $p$th powers.  The kernel is clearly $A_p$.  Done.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were referring to the quotient rather than the map, so that makes sense now.

Comment: @Randall No I didn't have the subscripts misplaced. For the finite abelian case the problem can be solved by showing both are elementary abelian with the same order

Comment: @crystal_math  Got it.

Comment: I still don't see how this is right in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to prove is false.  Let $A=S^1$, the group of unit-length complex numbers under multiplication.  Take the $p=2$ case.  Then $A_2 = \{x \in S^1 \mid x^2=1\} = \{\pm 1\}$.  However, $A^2 = S^1=A$ since squaring is surjective on the unit circle (every angle has a half-angle).  But then $A/A^2 = A/A$ is trivial and not isomorphic to $A_2$.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it doesn't generalize

Comment: You're welcome.  It was really bugging me.